# Op-amp noise figure

Tags: noise

If I have an opamp such as LM324 or a voltage regulator. How can I obtain noise figure experimentally?

For the opamp I would apply DC input and the ratio of output SNR to input SNR would be noise figure? How about for the regulator? A clear quantitative example would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

to determine the broadband noise figure, which I've learned to simply describe as **RNOISE**, while not being confused by the low-frequency charges-bouncing-from-traps that produces 1/F random noise, you need to measure the RMS output from DC to about 1 decade above the 1/F frequency corner.

Thus the upper bandwidth will vary, because 1/F corners vary.

Assuming the 1/F corner is 100 Hertz, then set the bandwidth to 1,000 Hertz.

- ground the Vin(+).
- install series RC from Vin(-) to Ground. Use an R of 100 ohms. Use capacitor suitable to set a high-pass-corner of 100Hz or so; why not. Exact cap is not critical, because 1,000 - 100 is about the same as 1,000 - 0, when expressed as dB.
- install feedback resistor for gain of 100x: 10,000 ohms is fine.
- add capacitor in parallel with 10,000 ohm, to set bandwidth to 1,000 Hz or so.

Now you have low-noise-contribution amplifier, and you are ready to measure the output random noise.

What noise voltage to expect?

A noisy opamp (typical opamp) will have RNOISE of 10,000 ohms, which is 12 nanoVolts rms / rootHertz.

In 1,000Hz bandwidth (actually 1,000 * pi/2 bandwidth), the input noise will be

- 12 nanovolts rms * sqrt(bandwidth) == 12nv * 31 == 360 nanovolts rms

The output Vnoise (we have a gain of 100X, remember) will be 360 nanovolts * gain, or 0.36 microvolts rms * 100x == 36 microVolts rms.

Some spectrum analyzers will display this. And a 7A22 scope plugin will display this, particularly with bandwidth set to 3KHz or 1KHz.

You may need another gain-of-100X amplifier, before meters will be usable.

What about Noise Figure?

Noise figure **requires** some noise density be defined.

The noise figure of this circuit is ----- set by the 100 ohm resistor (in the series RC DC_blocking network, to remove affect of opamp V_input_offset).

Minimum noise of the circuit will be 4nanovolts * sqrt (100 ohm / 1Kohm ohm) scaled by sqrt(bandwidth, scaled by gain.

Thus minimum will be 4nv * 0.31 * 31 * 100 = 4 microVolts.

Plus effect of pi / 2.